# Failed at the grpc@1.20.0 install script. while installing react

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

I am having a hard time installing **React Theme**. The problem is when I downloaded the theme and extracted it and went to the root directory...then tried to install it by running this command  `npm install`.

it gave this error

> Failed at the grpc@1.20.0 install script.

the error log was like this:

[image]

Comment: Try this thread on GHub: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/834

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After whole hours I find a hint from Github saying the problem was installing firebase which basically has `grpc` in them.

So what I did was to disable the antivirus or windows defender, whatever you have in your pc, and boom it will install safely.

this was the link I referred to https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/121

Comment: I did not disable anything, upgrading to firebase latest version fixed it or me