# I can't install any packages like react-bootstrap in my dashboard

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, npm-install

I have a problem in installing packages in my purchased dashboard for example I wanted to install react-bootstrap but I get this error:

node version: 12.16.1

npm version: 6.13.4

```
gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION
gyp ERR! stack Error: Cannot find module './_rules'
gyp ERR! stack Require stack:
gyp ERR! stack - C:\Users\Alisina\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\ajv\lib\compile\rules.js
gyp ERR! stack - C:\Users\Alisina\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\ajv\lib\ajv.js
gyp ERR! stack - C:\Users\Alisina\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\har-validator\lib\promise.js
gyp ERR! stack - C:\Users\Alisina\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\lib\har.js
gyp ERR! stack - C:\Users\Alisina\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js
gyp ERR! stack - C:\Users\Alisina\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\index.js
gyp ERR! stack - C:\Users\Alisina\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\install.js
gyp ERR! stack - C:\Users\Alisina\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\node-gyp.js
gyp ERR! stack - C:\Users\Alisina\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js
gyp ERR! stack     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)
gyp ERR! stack     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
gyp ERR! stack     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Alisina\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\ajv\lib\compile\rules.js:3:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
gyp ERR! stack     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
gyp ERR! stack     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Alisina\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=F:\\React Projects\\Lab\\Gogo react + node_modules\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=F:\\React Projects\\Lab\\Gogo react + node_modules\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown" "--napi_version=5" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72"
gyp ERR! cwd F:\React Projects\Lab\Gogo react + node_modules\node_modules\grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-gyp`.
gyp ERR! Try to update node-gyp and file an Issue if it does not help:
gyp ERR!     <https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues>
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Alisina\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=F:\React Projects\Lab\Gogo react + node_modules\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=F:\React Projects\Lab\Gogo react + node_modules\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (F:\React Projects\Lab\Gogo react + node_modules\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "F:\\React Projects\\Lab\\Gogo react + node_modules\\node_modules\\grpc\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd F:\React Projects\Lab\Gogo react + node_modules\node_modules\grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

and

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.20.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.20.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Alisina\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-17T16_27_34_386Z-debug.log
```

this is my package.json:

[image]

If you are reading this I will be grateful if you help me out

Comment: i can't able to view clear error which you faced. can you updated the error messge

Comment: @Rameshkumar, You can click on those images and see

Comment: @Rameshkumar I am editing my post don't worry

Comment: this link helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58935430/failed-at-the-grpc1-20-0-install-script-while-installing-react

Comment: Check grpc version .The newest version of grpc at this time, 1.24.2, is compatible with Node 12.x.

Comment: @Rameshkumar I disabled my antivirus programs and windows defender but it didn't work out, I still get the same result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211898/discussion-between-alisina-saemi-and-rameshkumar).

Answer (score 0):

you can install it by force. try this :

- add manually the library you want to install and its version in `package.json`
- delete `package-lock.json`
- then `npm install --force`